# Analytification of Poisson structures on an affine variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, poisson-geometry, analytic-geometry

It is well known that one can transfer every affine variety $X$ over $\mathbb{C}$ into an analytic space $X^{an}$ in a natural way. This process is called the analytification. My question is that does any Poisson structure on $X$ can be transferred into a Poisson structure on $X^{an}$ naturally?

Comment: Yes. A Poisson structure is a bivector field $\tau \in H^0(X,\wedge^2T_X)$ satisfying the Jacobi identity $[\tau ,\tau ]=0$. You can of course view it as an element of $H^0(X^{ac},\wedge^2T_{X^{ac}})$, still satisfying the same identity.

Comment: There is a natural morphism of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules $\mathcal{T}_X\wedge _{\mathcal{O}_X} \mathcal{T}_X  \to \mathcal{Hom}_{\mathcal{O}_X}(\Omega_X\wedge \Omega_X,\mathcal{O}_X)$. It is an isomorphism provided that $X$ is smooth. In my definition of a Poisson structure of $X$, I mean a global section of $\mathcal{Hom}_{\mathcal{O}_X}(\Omega_X\wedge \Omega_X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ satisfying the Jacobi condition with respect to the Schouten bracket. So, if $X$ is not smooth, how to transfer a given Poisson structure on $X$ to $X^{an}$?

Comment: By the way, if $X$ is not smooth then how to relate $(\mathcal{T}_X)^{an}$ and $\mathcal{T}_{X^{an}}$?